# EditTextPreference and default cursor position

Tags: android, android-edittext, text-cursor

This is mostly a pet peeve of mine, but it annoys me to no end that the default behavior or `EditTextPreference`s is to put the cursor at the beginning of the string. This makes NO sense at all to me. In almost any other interface known to man (fine, ME), focusing on a textfield automatically sends the cursor to the END.

So. Is there an (easy) way to override this? I know I can extend from `EditTextPreference` and call `setSelection()` manually, but this seems like a really complicated solution for such a simple problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up extending `EditTextPreference` and overriding the `showDialog` method:

```
  @Override
  protected void showDialog(Bundle state) {
    super.showDialog(state);
    Handler delayedRun = new Handler();
    delayedRun.post(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        EditText textBox = getEditText();
        textBox.setSelection(textBox.getText().length());
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Cool, but the EditText won't retain selection/cursor position on rotation anymore.

Answer (score 12):

Another angle on this: I just wind up setting 'selectAllOnFocus' to true either in the XML definition, or programmatically on the object.

It basically accomplished what I wanted: to have the end user be able to replace the contents immediately.

Comment: If you want to enable the user to replace the whole content and not just to append text to the end, that's the shortest way.

Answer (score 7):

Similar to lukeuser's solution, you can define the `OnPreferenceClickListener` inline or as a class variable:

```
final OnPreferenceClickListener _moveCursorToEndClickListener =
    new OnPreferenceClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference)
        {
            EditTextPreference editPref = (EditTextPreference)preference;
            editPref.getEditText().setSelection( editPref.getText().length() );
            return true;
        }
    };

[...]

EditTextPreference myPref = (EditTextPreference)findPreference( "MyPref" );
myPref.setOnPreferenceClickListener( _moveCursorToEndClickListener );
```

Or

```
EditTextPreference myPref = (EditTextPreference)findPreference( "MyPref" );
myPref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(
    new OnPreferenceClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference)
        {
            EditTextPreference editPref = (EditTextPreference)preference;
            editPref.getEditText().setSelection( editPref.getText().length() );
            return true;
        }
    } );
```

Answer (score 1):

I got another solution!

```
class opcl implements OnPreferenceClickListener{
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference pref) {
        EditTextPreference et = (EditTextPreference) pref;
        et.getEditText().setSelection(et.getText().length());
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then this for all your EditTextPreferences

```
opcl mopcl = new opcl();
    etpref1.setOnPreferenceClickListener(mopcl);
    etpref2.setOnPreferenceClickListener(mopcl);
    etpref3.setOnPreferenceClickListener(mopcl);
```

Answer (score 1):

This done the trick for me, just override `onPreferenceTreeClick()`:

```
/**
 * Automatically sets cursor to the last position in EditTextPreference
 *
 * @param preferenceScreen The {@link PreferenceScreen} that the
 *        preference is located in.
 * @param preference The preference that was clicked.
 * @return Whether the click was handled.
 */
@Override
public boolean onPreferenceTreeClick(PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen, @NotNull Preference preference) {
    super.onPreferenceTreeClick(preferenceScreen, preference);

    Preference clickedPreference = findPreference (preference.getKey ());
    if (clickedPreference instanceof EditTextPreference) // check if EditTextPreference
    {
        Editable editable = ((EditTextPreference) clickedPreference).getEditText().getText();
        Selection.setSelection(editable, editable.length()) ; // set the cursor to last position
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Keep in mind that I have used PreferenceFragment, but it is the same for PreferenceActivity.

This solution is adapted from http://www.phonesdevelopers.com/1816051/